# How to speed up a wordpress function with multiple loops?

Tags: php, functions, multi-taxonomy-query, loop

[image]

I am a PHP novice and wrote this function. It is an alphabetical navigation which shows only the letter that have posts in both that letter and the currently filtered "genero" taxonomy term.

I use multiple taxonomy queries to find "artistas" posts that, for example, are tagged as both "rock" and "funk".

The function works perfectly and outputs exactly what I want it to, but...

The multiple loops are really lagging the load time and, being the n00b that I am, am uncertain of how to optimize the function.

Any pointers or guidance would be **VERY** much appreciated. If you want I can trade time for time (i write some mean CSS) :)

thank you!

```
<?php
    function bam_artist_alfa() {
            $taxonomy = 'alfa';  
            $uri = my_url();
            $home = 'http://buenosairesmusic.com/';

            // save the terms that have posts in an array as a transient
            if ( false === ( $alphabet = get_transient( 'bam_archive_alphabet' ) ) ) {
                // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient
                $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);

                $alphabet = array();
                if($terms){
                    foreach ($terms as $term){
                        $alphabet[] = $term->slug;
                    }
                }
                set_transient( 'bam_archive_alphabet', $alphabet );
            } 

            if(strstr($uri, '/artista/') ) {
                $uri = str_replace('/artista/','/?alfa=', $uri);
                $uri = substr_replace($uri ,"",-1);
            }

            $all_link = removeqsvar($uri, 'alfa');
            $last = $all_link[strlen($all_link)-1]; 

            if($last == '?') $all_link = substr_replace($all_link ,"",-1);

            if($all_link == $home) 
                $all_link = $home.'artistas';

            if( isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['alfa']) ) {
                $is_alfa = (!is_tax('alfa') && !$_GET['alfa'] ? false : true );
            } else {
                $is_alfa = (!is_tax('alfa') ? false : true );
            }

            $all_current = ($is_alfa == true ? null : ' bg1 round-res' );


        ?>

                    <ul class="bbw bo alfa-nav c2">
                        <li class="all-link<?php echo $all_current; ?>">
                        <?php if(!$is_alfa) { echo 'A&ndash;Z'; } else { ?>

                            <a href="<?php echo $all_link; ?>">A&ndash;Z</a>
                        <?php }?>

                        </li>
    <?php
        $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        $genre = null;
        $orden = (isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['orden']) ? '&orden=fecha' : null);

        if( strstr($uri,'/genero/') ) {
            $genre = str_replace('/genero/','/?genero=', $uri);
            $genre = substr_replace($uri ,"",-1);
            $genre = explode('/',$genre);
            $genre = end($genre);
        } elseif( isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['genero']) ) {
            $genre = $_GET['genero'];
        }

        if(!empty($genre)) {
            $spaces = strpos($genre,' ');
            $genre = ($spaces === false ? $genre : explode(' ', $genre) );
        }

        function has_artists($i, $genre) {

            if(empty($genre)) {
                $termquery['tax_query'] = array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'alfa',
                        'terms' => $i,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                    ),
                );

                $termquery['post_type'] = 'artistas';
            } else {
                $alfaquery[] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'alfa',
                    'terms' => $i,
                    'field' => 'slug',
                );

                if(is_array($genre)) {
                    $genres[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'genero',
                        'terms' => $genre,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'operator' => 'AND'
                    );      
                } else {
                    $genres[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'genero',
                        'terms' => $genre,
                        'field' => 'slug',      
                    );
                }
                $termquery['tax_query'] = array_merge($genres, $alfaquery);
                $termquery['tax_query']['relation'] = "AND";
                $termquery['post_type'] = 'artistas';
            }

            $has_artists = get_posts($termquery);

            if($has_artists) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        foreach(range('a', 'z') as $i) : 

            $current = ($i == get_query_var($taxonomy)) ? "bg1 round-res" : "menu-item";

            if(empty($genre)) {
                $link = $home.'?alfa='.$i.$orden;
            } else {
                $genrestring = (is_array($genre) ? implode('+',$genre) : $genrestring = $genre );
                $link = $home.'?alfa='.$i.'&genero='.$genrestring.$orden;
            }

            if ( has_artists($i,$genre) && $i != get_query_var($taxonomy) ){ 
    ?>

                        <li class="<?php echo $current; ?>">
                            <?php printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $link, strtoupper($i) ) ?>
                        </li>
        <?php } else { ?>

                        <li class="<?php echo $current;  if($i != get_query_var($taxonomy)) {echo ' empty';} ?>">
                            <?php echo strtoupper($i); ?>
                        </li>
        <?php 
            }
            endforeach;
        ?>

                     </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just retrieve an array of alphabet/taxonomy terms that have posts. You do this, but doesn't actually use it. This function will return an array of non-empty (alphabet) terms:

(**Transient?** - unless you have multiple post types using this taxonomy, (*see below*) I'm not sure if much is gained from using transients - and you can just call to `get_terms` and use `wp_list_pluck` as shown). The following function uses transients.

```
 wpse50148_get_used_alpha(){

     if ( false === ( $alphabet = get_transient( 'bam_archive_alphabet' ) ) ) {
            //It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient
            $terms = get_terms('alfa');
            $alphabet =array();
            if($terms){
                $alphabet = wp_list_pluck($terms,'slug');
            }
            set_transient( 'bam_archive_alphabet', $alphabet );
        } 

      return $alphabet;
 }
```

**Don't forget to update the transient when a post is updated.**

This method assumes that the only post type using this taxonomy is 'artistas' - if it is being shared then a letter may claim to have artistas associated with it (in your menu) when it does not.

#### Shared taxonomy work-around

To get round this, you would have to query the posts and then loop through them and collect their terms. Either way - only 1, not 26 queries are being performed to get the 'used' alphabet. A transient would be more obviously time-saving in this scenario.

#### Usage:

```
  $alphabet = wpse50148_get_used_alpha();

   foreach(range('a', 'z') as $i) : 
      if( in_array($i,$alphabet) ){
           //Letter has terms
      }else{
           //Letter does not have terms
      }
   endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use the transients API yet but in this case I think it's a good choice. You use it but only for a small part of the data.

To cache artists per alfa and genre you could do something like this (I assume):

```
if ( false === ( $has_artists = get_transient( "bam_artist_$i_$genre" ) ) ) {
    $has_artists = get_posts($termquery);
    set_transient( "bam_artist_$i_$genre", $has_artists );
}
```